# Updating a bunch of rows is it transaction based or row based?

Tags: mysql, jpa, concurrency, eclipselink, jpql

I've a table with a column that needs to be constantly recomputed and I want this table to be scallable. Users must be able to write on it as well.

It's difficult to test this type of things without having a server and concurrent users, at least I don't know how.
So is one of those two options viable ?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Abean {
   @EJB
   private MyService myService;
   @Asynchronous
   public void computeTheData(){
      long i = 1;
      long numberOfRows = myService.getCountRows(); // gives the number of row in the table
      while(i<numberOfRows){
        myService.updateMyRow(i);
      }
      computeTheData(); // recursion so it never stops, I'm wondering if this wouldn't spawn more threads and if it would be an issue.
   }
}

public class MyService implements MyServiceInterface{
    ...
    public void updateMyRows(int row){
       Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MyEntity WHERE m.id=:id");
       Query.setParameter("id", row);
       List<MyEntity> myEntities = (MyEntity) query.getResultList();
       myEntity.computeData();
    }
}
```

VS

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Abean {
   @EJB
   private MyService myService;
   @Asynchronous
   public void computeTheData(){
      myService.updateAllRows();
   }
}

public class MyService implements MyServiceInterface{
        ...
    public void updateAllRows(int page){
       Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MyEntity");
       List<MyEntity> myEntities = (MyEntity) query.getResultList();
       myEntity.computeData();
    }
}
```

Is any of this viable ? I'm using mysql and the engine for tables is innoDB.

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand the question. What is it you want to achieve? Do you want to test the performance and you want to write some test code, that would update every row in the database, even multiple times (according the infinite recursion in example 1)?

Comment: @OndrejM I have a column that is hot_score which is a function of time ( reddit algorithm). I want to be able to tell my db to select the top 20 of highest hotscores. However since it's a function of time I need to constantly update it. But if I constantly update it then users can't write on it. So I'm trying to find a solution for this.

Comment: OK, I understand that you need to support concurrent updates - both from frequent background job and from users. You might run into issues if you use optimistic locking. I suggest pessimistic locking to lock modified entities during transactions. I will later explain in a full answer, if you wish to see code example.

Comment: @OndrejM I'd much appreciate that. Actually I'm learning Cassandra to migrate my db to it. Do you think it can be a good solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pessimistic locking to lock modified rows before update, so that manual modifications by a user are not in conflict with background updates. If you did not use locking, your user's modifications would sometimes be rolled back, if they collide with background job having modified the same row.

Also, with pessimistic locking, your user may encounter rollback if her transaction waits to acquire the lock for longer than timeout happends. To prevent this, you should make all transactions, which use pessimistic locks, as short as possible. Therefore, the background job should create a new transaction for every row or small group of rows, if it may run longer than reasonable time. Locks are released only after the transaction finishes (User will wait until lock is released).

Example of how your MyService could look like, running every update in separate transaction (in reality, you may run multiple updates in batch in single transaction, passing list or range of ids as parameter to updateMyRows):

```
public class MyService implements MyServiceInterface{
        ...
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) // this will create a new transaction when running this method from another bean, e.g. from Abean
    public void updateMyRows(int row){
       TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = em.createQuery(SELECT m FROM MyEntity WHERE m.id=:id", MyEntity.class);
       query.setParameter("id", row);
       query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE); // this will lock all entities retrieved by the query
       List<MyEntity> myEntities = query.getResultList();
       if (!myEntities.isEmpty()) {
         myEntities.get(0).computeData();
       }
    }
}
```

When you use only id in where condition, you may consider `em.find(row, MyEntity.class, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).computeData()` instead of using a query (add null pointer check after em.find())

Other notes:

It is not clear from the question how you trigger the background job. Running the job infinitely, as you wrote in the example, would on one hand NOT create additional threads (as you call the methond on the same bean, annotations are not considered recursively). On the other hand, if there is an exception, your background job should at least handle exceptions so that it will not be stopped. You may also want to add some wait time between subsequent executions.

It is better to run background jobs as scheduled jobs. One possible option is `@Schedule` annotation instead of `@Asynchronous`. You may specify the frequency, in which the job will be executed in background. It is then good to check in the beginning of your job, whether previous execution is finished. Another option with Java EE 7 is to use [ManagedScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedScheduledExecutorService.html) to trigger a background job periodically at specified interval.

Comment: Thanks that helps me a lot. When you write TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW for a new transaction, I suppose that's not needed if my service is stateless ? I thought a function in a stateless bean is the entry point of a transaction and the end of the function is the end of the transaction (that it was done automatically in the background).

Comment: I put the transaction attribute there to enforce ALWAYS creating a new transaction. In your code, it is probably not necessary, as you are calling the service from a non-transactional bean. But it would matter if you called MyService from another EJB. By default, it would reuse caller's transaction and all locks would be held by single transaction. When the code is sensitive to how transactions are created, it is good to be explicit and require always a new transaction.